# How to delete/update document from AWS ElasticSearch when exact index which consist the document is not known

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, aws-elasticsearch

**Background:**

We have an AWS ElasticSearch with multiple indexes e.g. index-1, index-2.
We have an alias "read-alias" associated with both index-1 & index-2. Also we have "write-alias" which is associated only with index-2.

So we read from both indexes but write to only index-2.

**Problem:**

As long as read/search requests concern we are fine but for "delete" and "Update" requests we have a problem.

Because we do not know in which index the document is. We have Document Id. But when we try to delete or update the document we frequently receive "document missing exception".

**Probable cause:**

We are using "write-alias" for update & Delete requests which is pointing to only index-2. So for any document which is present in index-1 we receive error.

How to solve this,

> How to read and write from both indexes? Should we redirect update
>   & delete requests to both indexes ?
>   How to write when the index is not known.

I'm new to ElasticSearch world so any help is highly appreciated.

ElasticSearch version - 5.1 and 2.3